# Implementing a Stencil SQLite DB in my Jest test is giving me a wasm file error

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, jestjs, capacitor, stenciljs

In my Capacitor-React application I am using an sqlite db; specifically: https://github.com/capacitor-community which uses the jeep-sqlite stencil library (https://github.com/jepiqueau/jeep-sqlite). The jeep-sqlite stencil library requires you to have a `sql-wasm.wasm` inside of the app's `public/assests/` folder.

I am hoping to write some unit tests with Jest where each test has a db instance that I can seed and use to test. I've ran into an issue implementing this db instance in my test file where jeep-sqlite cannot load the specified wasm file. Here is my test file I am trying to implement

```
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { CapacitorSQLite, SQLiteConnection, SQLiteDBConnection } from '@capacitor-community/sqlite';
import { defineCustomElements as jeepSqlite, applyPolyfills, JSX as LocalJSX  } from 'jeep-sqlite/loader';
// ...

const dbName = config.databaseName;

type StencilToReact<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P] & Omit<HTMLAttributes<Element>, 'className'> & {
        class?: string;
    };
} ;

declare global {
    export namespace JSX {
        interface IntrinsicElements extends StencilToReact<LocalJSX.IntrinsicElements> {
        }
    }
}

applyPolyfills().then(() => {
    jeepSqlite(window, {});
});

it('test', async () => {
  const sqlite: SQLiteConnection = new SQLiteConnection(CapacitorSQLite);

  const jeepEl = document.createElement('jeep-sqlite');
  document.body.appendChild(jeepEl);
  const element = await customElements.whenDefined('jeep-sqlite');
  
  const assetPath = resolve(`${__dirname}/../../../public/assets`); // we've also tried '.../assets/sql-wasm.wasm'
  jeepEl.setAttribute('wasmPath', assetPath ); // attempt to set the wasmPath
  
  const sqlite: SQLiteConnection = new SQLiteConnection(CapacitorSQLite);
  await sqlite.initWebStore();
  
  const ret = await sqlite.checkConnectionsConsistency();
  const isConn = (await sqlite.isConnection(dbName, false)).result;
  let db: SQLiteDBConnection;
  if (ret.result && isConn) {
      db = await sqlite.retrieveConnection(dbName, false);
  } else {
      db = await sqlite.createConnection(dbName, false, 'no-encryption', 1, false);
  }
  try {
      await db.open();
  } catch (err) {
      // ...   
  }
  // ...
}
```

And we get the following errors:

```
console.error
      Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
          at Object.dispatchError (<omitted>/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/xhr-utils.js:63:19)
          at Request.<anonymous> (<omitted>/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/XMLHttpRequest-impl.js:655:18)
          at Request.emit (node:events:539:35)
          at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (<omitted>/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/http-request.js:121:14)
          at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:527:28)
          at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:454:9)
          at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
          at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
          at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
          at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) undefined

      at VirtualConsole.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29:45)

    console.warn
      Aborted(both async and sync fetching of the wasm failed)

      at E (node_modules/jeep-sqlite/dist/cjs/node_modules/sql.js/dist/sql-wasm.js:101:136)
      at ab (node_modules/jeep-sqlite/dist/cjs/node_modules/sql.js/dist/sql-wasm.js:102:149)
      at node_modules/jeep-sqlite/dist/cjs/node_modules/sql.js/dist/sql-wasm.js:103:256

    console.warn
      failed to asynchronously prepare wasm: RuntimeError: Aborted(both async and sync fetching of the wasm failed). Build with -sASSERTIONS for more info.

      at node_modules/jeep-sqlite/dist/cjs/node_modules/sql.js/dist/sql-wasm.js:158:377

    console.warn
      Aborted(RuntimeError: Aborted(both async and sync fetching of the wasm failed). Build with -sASSERTIONS for more info.)

      at E (node_modules/jeep-sqlite/dist/cjs/node_modules/sql.js/dist/sql-wasm.js:101:136)
      at node_modules/jeep-sqlite/dist/cjs/node_modules/sql.js/dist/sql-wasm.js:158:425

  ● getLookupRecordData › updateOfflineData › test db

    both async and sync fetching of the wasm failed

      at Object.Module.onAbort (node_modules/jeep-sqlite/dist/cjs/node_modules/sql.js/dist/sql-wasm.js:40:20)
      at E (node_modules/jeep-sqlite/dist/cjs/node_modules/sql.js/dist/sql-wasm.js:101:106)
      at ab (node_modules/jeep-sqlite/dist/cjs/node_modules/sql.js/dist/sql-wasm.js:102:149)
      at node_modules/jeep-sqlite/dist/cjs/node_modules/sql.js/dist/sql-wasm.js:103:256

  ● getLookupRecordData › updateOfflineData › test db

    RuntimeError: Aborted(RuntimeError: Aborted(both async and sync fetching of the wasm failed). Build with -sASSERTIONS for more info.). Build with -sASSERTIONS for more info.

      at E (node_modules/jeep-sqlite/dist/cjs/node_modules/sql.js/dist/sql-wasm.js:101:154)
      at node_modules/jeep-sqlite/dist/cjs/node_modules/sql.js/dist/sql-wasm.js:158:425
```

So I guess a few questions I have are:

1. Is there anything that stands out as wrong above code?
2. Is there are preferred way to run a stencil library in Jest (ie do we need mount the component within JSDom, or some other machanism?)
3. Are there any common gotchas when testing with web components?

Any hints would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: did you ever solve this? I am facing a very similar issue, also stuck on wasm loading

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I did find a solution and just posted it below.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this issue.

The solution that worked was spinning up a server before running the test. So we added the following scripts to our package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "cp node_modules/sql.js/dist/sql-wasm.wasm build/assets && serve -l 80 build/",
    "test": "{Your test script here}",
    "test:serve": "npm-run-all --parallel -r serve test", 
  },
```

Then we ran npm run test:serve when running the test. The test:serve script serves a local host that jeepSqlite is trying to reach out to in order to retrieve the sql-wasm.wasm file.